# How to get a complete coverage in all package golang

Tags: go, testing, integration-testing

I have just 24h working with Go so I am super new to this.

I'm trying to get a complete test conversion but when I run

```
go test -cover new-project/anto/... .
```

in **new-project/anto/mon** it shows me that I have 51.8% coverage but in reality I have more coverage because there are tests that are tested in **new-project/anto/integration** where I have a test file that I import the **new-project/anto/mon** for testing.

The thing is that as I was reading Golang only takes the tests if they are in the same folder but having separate files does not detect it correctly.

I was wondering if there is a way to get the full coverage.

```
go test -cover new-project/anto/... .
?       new-project/anto/       [no test files]
ok      new-project/anto/conf   6.060s  coverage: 73.1% of statements
ok      new-project/anto/integration    43.309s coverage: [no statements]
?       new-project/anto/integration/conf   [no test files]
?       new-project/anto/integration/mocks  [no test files]
?       new-project/anto/integration/utils  [no test files]
ok      new-project/anto/logs   0.024s  coverage: 70.5% of statements
ok      new-project/anto/metric 0.012s  coverage: 59.0% of statements
ok      new-project/anto/mon    1.612s  coverage: 51.8% of statements
?       new-project/anto/anotherComponents  [no test files]
```

Doing some research, I found a **go-acc plugin** that validates all the packages, the curious thing is that mon instead of having 51.8% now has 29.8%.

```
go-acc new-project/anto/... .
?       new-project/anto/   [no test files]
ok      new-project/anto//conf  5.030s  coverage: 73.1
ok      new-project/anto//integration   43.117s coverage: 73.5
?       new-project/anto//integration/conf  [no test files]
?       new-project/anto//integration/mocks [no test files]
?       new-project/anto//integration/utils [no test files]
ok      new-project/anto//logs  0.008s  coverage: 22.3
ok      new-project/anto//metric    0.020s  coverage: 59.0
ok      new-project/anto//mon   1.460s  coverage: 29.8
?       new-project/anto//anotherComponents     [no test files]
?       new-project/anto/   [no test files]
```

Answer (score 12):

The first command will generate `coverage.out` for all packages. The second parses the `coverage.out` and outputs the results:

```
go test ./...  -coverpkg=./... -coverprofile ./coverage.out
go tool cover -func ./coverage.out
```

Sample output:

```
golang.org/x/example/stringutil/reverse.go:21: Reverse      100.0%
total:                                         (statements) 100.0%
```

For more details see the various `help` outputs:

- `go help test`
- `go help testflags`
- `go help packages`
- `go tool cover --help`

Comment: Hello Matthew Warman, thanks a lot for your help! but when I try this option all my test are failure

go test ./...  -coverpkg=./... -coverprofile ./coverage.out
?    new-project/anto [no test files]
FAIL new-project/anto/conf [build failed]
FAIL new-project/anto/integration 0.012s
?    new-project/anto/integration/conf
?    new-project/anto/integration/mocks
?    new-project/anto/integration/utils
FAIL new-project/anto/logv 
FAIL new-project/anto/metric 
FAIL new-project/anto/mon 

go tool cover -func ./coverage.out
total: (statements) 0.0%